# Firebase: How to get parent of parent node?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have node and I'm trying to get the node parent.

[image]

I'm trying to get the black line data.

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Params.GENRESCOMMENTS).child(video.getGenre())
            .child(video.getVideoID());
    Log.d(TAG,"Query: " + query.toString());
    options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Comment>().setQuery(query,Comment.class).build();

    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Comment,CommentsSingleVideoView>(options) {

        @Override
        public CommentsSingleVideoView onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.comment_item,parent,false);
            return new CommentsSingleVideoView(view);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(CommentsSingleVideoView holder, int position, final Comment model) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Model: " + model.toString());
            final String videoID = (String) this.getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getKey();
            Log.d(TAG,"Video ID: " + videoID);
            final String userCommentUID = model.getUserCommentUID();
            holder.tvUserName.setText(model.getUserName());
            holder.tvComment.setText(model.getComment());
            holder.tvDate.setText(model.getUploadDate());
```

This line of code `final String videoID = (String) this.getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getKey();` gets me only the red line.
I need to get the black line data. 
What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried the answer?

Answer (score 0):

To get the parent node, try the following inside `onBindViewHolder`:

```
 String videoID = this.getRef(position).getKey();
```

---

`getRef(position)` will return the source location of your reference and `getKey()` will retrieve the node.

The code from firebaseui docs:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public DatabaseReference  getRef(int position) {
    return mSnapshots.getSnapshot(position).getRef();
}
```

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java#L113

Comment: Sorry for the delay. But your suggestion its not the answer that i seek for. I need to get the data on the black line. Your code brings me the data in the red line.

Comment: Hi, is this the data on the black line `child(video.getVideoID())`

Comment: Where should i write it?

Comment: In the comment here, I'm just asking child.getVideoID what does it give you?

Comment: It gives me the parent in the red box